# How to make 'cat' in Linux to interpret control characters

Tags: linux, escaping, echo, cat

Consider the following echo command:

```
 echo -e "at\r"
```

which produces the output `at` on the command line, i.e. the \r special character has been interpreted. I want to do the exact same thing with some text in a file. Supposing the exact same sequence

```
at\r
```

is written to a file named `at.txt`, then I want to display it on the terminal. But

```
cat at.txt
```

gives the output

```
at\r
```

what is not what I want. I want the special sequence \r to be interpreted, not just printed on the terminal. Anyone any idea?

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: Would `echo -e "$(cat file)"` work? (For small files)

Comment: Or if the file is very large you could try xargs: `cat file | xargs echo -ne`

Comment: The first suggestion works (knittl), the second suggestion (Lee) produces a string 'atr'.

Comment: It seems that `xargs` uses \ as a special character. To fix this you can tell it to not to: `cat file | xargs --null echo -ne`

Answer (score 15):

Why not:

```
while read -r line; do echo -e $line; done < at.txt
```

Comment: Leading whitespaces are missing in the output. I solved this by adding "IFS=" and enclosing $line in double quotes: while IFS= read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done <at.txt

Answer (score 12):

You can simply:

```
echo -e $(cat at.txt)
```

Comment: Does not respect line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `echo` command interprets the common backslash escapes. But in a file you have to interpret, or convert it in a similar way. The `sed` program can do this.

```
sed -e 's/\\r/\r/' < at.txt
```

But I learned somethere here, also. The external `echo` command behaves differently from the internal one.

```
/bin/echo "\r"
```

Has different output than

```
echo "\r"
```

But basically you need a filter to convert the litteral `\r` string to a single byte 0x0D.

Comment: That's simply not correct … try `echo "\r"` vs. `echo -e "\r"`. If it was the shell, both commands would output the same string.

Comment: The external echo behaves differently. And echo of sh behaves differently than echo of bash too