# Python - When saving text to a file, it adds redundant characters

Tags: python, linux, ssh

In my Linux server, I have a Python code that tracks an SSH connection, copies every character the user enters or is generated by the system, and saves it in a file.

This is the function that is called to store new text:

```
async def writeToFile(filename, data):
try:
    path = f'{RECORDINGS_PATH}/{filename}'
    f = open(path, "a")
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(f'error writing to recordings file')
```

The problem is, that with the expected characters, it also saves in the file, redundant characters with a prefix of [

example:  `[4;48H[4;48H[4;48Hs`

When printing the file with Linux cat command, the output is as expected, but when opening the file in a text editor, it shows also the redundant characters.

The problem is that our clients watch the files with a text editor.

There is a way to save the file, so the client will see the expected text?

Answer (score 2):

Those characters are control sequences that instruct the terminal to move the cursor to a specific position.

`[` indicates the start of a control sequence.
`4;48` represents the row and column coordinates to which the cursor should be moved.
`H` indicates the end of the control sequence and instructs the terminal to position the cursor accordingly.

For sorting out why the characters are not visible when using `cat`, this post may be helpful: [How to make 'cat' in Linux to interpret control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175304/how-to-make-cat-in-linux-to-interpret-control-characters)

Comment: So, in short, it's doing the correct thing; their code captured all the characters emitted by the SSH session, and it was emitting control characters to modify the cursor position in the client's shell, which were dutifully captured and written with everything else.

Comment: Understand, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: There is a way that those control characters will not be visible to the client in his text editor?

Comment: You could process the file and remove the undesired characters with regex.